# How to pass PHP variable value to html input box from external PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

**HTML FILE**

```html
<body>

<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name">
<label for="name">name</label>

<script type="text/javascript" src="PHPfile.php"></script>
</body>
```

**Separate PHP FILE**

I have done MySQL query, and I have query value in `$row['name']`.

How can I put this value in the HTML input box?

```php
<?PHP

**some code here**
//value in $row['name']
//confirmed by echo $row['name'];
// now I want to pass this value to my HTML input box

echo "<script>
var name = <?php echo $row['name'] ?>;
document.getElementById(name).value='name';
window.location.href='htmlpage.html';
</script>";

?>
```

I tried this but this didn't work. I got the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in...
```

I have tried to provide custom variable to `var name` and then `document.getElementByID` line. Still, it doesn't work.

Any Solution?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this? Is there any need to open a new PHP tag within the PHP tag?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```php
<?php

/**some code here**/
//value in $row['name']
//confirmed by echo $row['name'];
// now I want to pass this value to my HTML input box

echo '<script>
document.getElementById("name").value = "' . $row['name'] . '";
</script>';
?>
```

or same thing if more complex HTML/script needed:

```php
<?php

/**some code here**/
//value in $row['name']
//confirmed by echo $row['name'];
// now I want to pass this value to my HTML input box

?>
<script>
document.getElementById("name").value = "<?=$row['name'];?>";
</script>
<?php

/* more php code */

?>
```

If you still get the same error message, than the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Hi your first answer gives a blank page and it stays in php page and in second solution i get ```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "?"``` as error

Comment: Script is not visible on the page, check source.

Comment: This is how i linked with HTML ```<script type="text/javascript" src="PHPpage.php"></script>``` php file name is correct. I have double checked.

Comment: Than you don't need `<script></script>` tags inside the php file, it should output javascript only. no html. You should update your question with correct filenames and explain what code belong to what file, etc.

Comment: See I have one HTML file and I've connected that HTML file with external php file. Now i want to retrieve value from database back to my HTML page. So I'm using javascript to put values back to my html page. so I retrieved the values in php variable and now i'm trying to post it in html input box.

Answer (score 0):

To echo a variable in a string ( in  php ) we can use concatenation `" . " $var['code'] ". "` or template string `{ $var["code"] }`

**PHPfile.php**

```
<?php

$row = ["name" => "something"];
echo  "
    let input = document.getElementById('name');
    input.value =  '{$row['name']}';
    setTimeout(()=>{
     window.location.href='htmlpage.html';
    } ,2000)
     "
   
?>
```

> For echoing variables in string use `{$var}` instead of simple concatenation

**Extended answer**

**index.php**

```
   <?php
   // all querys here  ... getting results from db 
   // assuming result 
   
     $row = [
      "username" => "xxxxxxxxx",
      "email" => "xxxxx@example.com"
     ];
     
     $name = $row['username'];
   ?>
     
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Damn Forms ! </title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form action="file.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 
     <label for="name">Name <span class="red">*</span></label>
 
     <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name " value="<?= $name ?>">
   
     <!-- sending values to another php file -->
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>

   </form>
    
   </body>
   </html>
```

**file.php**

```
  <?php
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
   }
  ?>
  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Input Form </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="" value="<?= $name ?>" />
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @Sehnas Khan Does this answer solves your question ?

Comment: Getting a blank page in browser. As per the code it should redirect me to the HTML page and give me the retrieved value in the input box. I'm getting a blank page

Comment: @Sehnas Khan let me check it once

Comment: Error is in this line ```document.getElementById(name).value;
alert('Incorrect username or password. Try again!');``` if I skip ```document...``` line than alert pop up works fine.

Comment: @Sehnas Khan Why are you redirecting to a new html page ? It will delete the input value also I corrected the code

Comment: why concatenate like this: `"some string" . " $var ". "some other string"` and not like: `"some string" .  $var . "some other string"` or even `"some string $var some other string"`

Comment: @Cornel Raiu  Actually what you wrote is correct for variable like `$var` but it will lead to an error if `$var["some"]` .... So as per OP I used that to make OP understand easily ! Also I could have stored the variable inside ...... Ah! Just too much code sorry for being to sluggish :-)

Comment: what is ```name``` and ```something``` in your code?

Comment: @Sehnas Khan Since I don't know what data are you retrieving from dB I just made an assumption ... Nothing important at all

Comment: Data is retrieved in PHP array variable ```$row['name']``` as I have mentioned above. If I post the entire code it will be long so I have kept it short. If I do ```echo $row['name'];``` I get the output. Now I just need to pass it to the HTML input box. I'm trying to do it using JavaScript. I hope I'm clear this time.

Comment: In simple terms, I have an array value in PHP variable ```$row['name']```. I am trying to pass it to another HTML file using JavaScript. How do I pass it?

Comment: @Sehnas Khan There are 2 options for you to pass the data to another file one using requests like get ( only if your file is not static one ) and other is using JavaScript to store values inside localStorage  ( I think it is what are you looking for ) ..! Tell me which one you would prefer ? I'll update my answer accordingly ! ...

Comment: Whichever you feel comfortable with. My file is not static as I'm using MySQL as my database. Retrieving values from MySql using the PHP Mysqli query.

Comment: @Sehnas Khan I think you don't require js at all in here ! Just PHP !  Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 answers already, but my way of doing it would be....

HTML

```
<body>
    
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name">
<label for="name">name</label>
<div id="externalPHP"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("externalPHP").innerHTML='<object type="type/php" data="PHPfile.php" ></object>';//javascript
$('#externalPHP').load('PHPfile.php');//jQuery
</script>
</body>
```

The php file

```
<?PHP
    
**some code here**
//value in $row['name']
//confirmed by echo $row['name'];
// now I want to pass this value to my HTML input box
    
echo '<script>document.getElementById("name").value='."$row['name']".';</script>';
?>
```